# strange backtrace from android debuggerd

Tags: android, c++, backtrace, android-native-library

I am confused about some backtrace dump from android debuggerd

```
backtrace:
#00 pc 00019d5c  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01 pc 0001d207  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_wait_ex(void volatile*, bool, int, bool, timespec const*)+86)
#02 pc 00064303  /system/lib/libc.so (NonPI::MutexLockWithTimeout(pthread_mutex_internal_t*, bool, timespec const*)+154)
#03 pc 006030a1  /data/app/com.xxx.xxxxx/lib/arm/libB.so (std::__ndk1::mutex::lock()+4)
#04 pc 000e63e9  /data/app/com.xxx.xxxxx/lib/arm/libA.so (A::Test1::InTest2()+28)
#05 pc 000e63bd  /data/app/com.xxx.xxxxx/lib/arm/libA.so (A::Test1::InTest1()+160)
#06 pc 000637f5  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
#07 pc 0001e019  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+24)
```

I am sure that I don't dynamicly link libB.so to libA.so. but the backtrace show `A::Test1::InTest2()` call `libB.so (std::__ndk1::mutex::lock()+4)`

What is the meaning of this backtrace.

Comment: How *do* you link `libA`? And how do you link the application you run?

Comment: write some jni code and link libA.so @Someprogrammerdude